# How long will take the apps registered in v2 app portal show up in Enterprise Application in azure portal?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Registered an app in v2 portal apps.dev.microsoft.com, it says 'This application will be registered in the Azure Active Directory instance used to manage your account', now 3 hours passed, when I go to 'enterprise applications' tab in azure portal-active directory, i still didnt see it there, why? how long will it take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enterprise applications blade represents ***Service Principals***, rather than applications.  [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects) an excellent doc that walks through details of the difference between an application & service principal.

A Service Principal can be thought of as an instantiation of your application into the tenant.  In the example of multi-tenancy, you as an app developer may register an application, then have multiple tenants sign in & consent to the app.  At that point, each of those tenants will get a Service Principal provisioned into their tenant and it will show up in the Enterprise Apps section.

To prompt a Service Principal to be provisioned in the same tenant as the app registration, you simply need to complete a sign in request and consent to the application.  It should show up after that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, what does 'This application will be registered in the Azure Active Directory instance used to manage your account' mean then? Where to access it in the azure portal?

Comment: No problem @TOMMYWANG, I haven't personally experienced this message. But if you got it after registering the app in apps.dev.microsoft.com, then I presume it to mean that the app has been saved and registered to Azure AD to the account/tenant that just registered it; however, as I explained a service principal in your tenant has not been created yet.